# Validating FileField using wtforms

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid, wtforms

I'm trying to validate `FileField` field from wtforms, however, I get the following exception, when file is selected:

```
File "forms.py", line 15, in check_cover # my forms.py file with custom validator
  if field.data:
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/cgi.py", line 637, in __len__
  return len(self.keys())
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/cgi.py", line 626, in keys
  raise TypeError("not indexable")
```

Validator code and form itself:

```
def check_cover(form, field):
  if field.data: # this line raises exception
    filename = field.data.filename
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].strip(".")
    if not ext.lower() in ALLOWED_IMG_EXT:
        raise validators.ValidationError('Has to be an image')
  else:
    raise validators.ValidationError('Please, provide an image')

class BlogPostForm(Form):
  title = TextField('Title',
                    validators=[validators.Length(min=1, max=200)])
  content = TextAreaField('Content', [validators.Length(min=1)],
                          id='blog-content')
  cover_pic = FileField('Cover image', validators=[check_cover])
```

And html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ form.title }}
  {{ form.content }}
  {{ form.cover_pic }}
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Validator works for the case, when file is not selected, but as soon as I select a file, it fails on that check. I could try to access `filename`, instead of just `data` (`field.data.filename`) and it works fine, but only if a file is actually selected. If no file is selected it fails with `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'value'`. So that is understandable.

Could it be due to the fact that I'm using python3? How can I solve this issue?

Thanks,
Rapolas

Comment: Have you reached out the the `WTForms` folks? This might be a bug related to porting this library to py3k.

Comment: You may also want to check out this link http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html#acts-like-set it describes this section of `cgi.py`

Answer (score 2):

First, you should check if a file is selected:

```
if type(form.cover_pic.data) is not UnicodeType:
```

Also, you have an error using strip method instead of split:

```
ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].strip(".")
```